# How to gather info similar to panopticlick.eff.org

Tags: cookies, privacy, user-tracking

I saw that the website http://panopticlick.eff.org/ gather info about your browser, which makes you unique, even without cookies or IP tracking.

My question: How do you use javascript to see this info?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a download in [this article on corephp.com](http://www.corephp.com/blog/hardcore-javascript-browser-and-computer-fingerprinting/) that includes javascript to fingerprint browsers and convert the results to an MD5 hash sum - probably not as heavyweight as panopticlick but it is pretty good.